# How to get the Facebook logged in users Friends details and send them message from C# application where logged in user is not the admin

Tags: asp.net

How to get the Facebook logged in users Friends details and send them message from C# application where logged in user is not the admin?

Comment: You might want to consider reading this http://stackoverflow.com/FAQ and posting the code you've tried so far and be a bit more explicit about the nature of the problem you're having. Check this link for tips on constructing questions  http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Non admin users can retrieve their facebook friends if in the app created in facebook has its sandbox mode as off. 
to send message u can user send dialoge provided by facebook "http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/"